# Improper integrals $\int_{a_1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Analyze the convergence of:$$\int_{a_1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt$$

and

$$\int_{a_1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\cos(t)}{t}dt$$

and prove that there exists $a_n$ such that

$$\int_{a_{n-1}}^{a_n}\frac{1+\cos(t)}{t}dt=\frac{1}{n}$$

I tried to integrate by parts, but I don't know how to work with this sequence $a_n$

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry. I edited it.

Comment: [Differentiation under integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral#Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: integrate by parts $\int_a^b \frac{\cos(s)}{t}dt  = \frac{\sin(t)}{t}|_a^b +\int_a^b \frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}dt$ therefore $\int_a^\infty \frac{\cos(s)}{t}dt = -\frac{\sin(a)}{a}+ \int_a^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t^2}dt$